# Getting responses to specific events with Otto

Tags: android, retrofit, otto

I have a two stage process where I upload images, get an image id, then attach that id to a post and create a post on a server. I'm using Otto, Tape, and Retrofit to handle the nuts of bolts of this, most of which is going well already. I can foresee a problem in the future though where I try to create two posts at once, since I'll be getting image uploaded events in two response listeners at the same time.

Does anyone have a go-to solution for differentiating which listeners are listing for which events, especially when they're the same types of events?

Should I just generate a random UUID and pass that around with my events, then use it to identify responses to specific requests?